# jQuery Validation - Overwriting core validation method

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery Validation plug-in.

I have overwritten the required rule since mine depends on some custom condition as in following:

```
$.validator.addMethod("required", function(value, element) {
    console.log("required", element);

    return someCondition && value != null;
}, "This is is required.");
```

When the form is validated however, I see that `"required"` is printed twice for each element meaning the function is called twice. As soon as I change the method name to `"myRequired"` and add the following class rule, the function is called just once as it should be.

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
    required : {
        myRequired: true
    }
});
```

It appears that the core required method is still intact and called even if I add a method with the same name. Is there anyway to entirely overwrite the core rule method?

Comment: Which validation plugin are you using.

Comment: I'm using jQuery Validation plugin.

Comment: Tom, links are always usefull, there many "jQuery Validation" plugins. However i presume you are using this one? http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: @Blowsie That's correct.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're not overriding it, but adding another method to it. To override it, try this:

```
$.validator.methods.required = function(value, element, param) {
    console.log("required", element);

    return someCondition && value != null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.extend` to do this:

```
$.extend($.validator, {
    required: function(value, element) {
        console.log("required", element);
        return someCondition && value != null;
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you have any example or link?